Tool for combining screenshots for comparison
I have two screenshots (complete or of parts of the screen) from two scenarios I want to compare. Instead of using an image editor to create the comparison-combination of the images, I would like a tool which, given two images:

Places them side-by-side or one-over-the-other
Draws a border between them
Renders some text under/above/to the side of each (to distinguish them)
(Potentially) if they are of different sizes or at different positions, but do match-mostly - finds the best match and places each of them on a larger common canvas which does correspond perfectly; the rest of the canvas needs to be transparency or some fixed background color

I realize that the three first items are not very difficult to achieve with some scripting and a library for image editing, but the fourth is more complex.
Anyway, required:

Gratis
Runs on Linux

Desired:

Libre
Support for wide range of image formats
Actively maintained


I use Paint.NET for that with 2 layers and the top layer set as "difference". But I see that this may be hard to set up. A dedicated tool would indeed be nice.

check image magic scripts there should be one aimed at "differs" by overlay but adding a wrapper would probably require a little HTML magic to draw 3 frames <img src=... left.png right.png and combined.png should only be a dozen lines with replacement filenames as have done similar for PDF using right.pdf left.pdf and just script the file names as body text.

@KJ: So, an HTML which uses the two images, then rendering that HTML, but to a file rather than to the screen... that's a neat idea.

@einpoklum hmm not precisely what I meant but yes that variation might work, if one was a frame as transparent or non transparent and a second is overlaid with a drag and drop/spreadable frame it would allow manual move and align. But I suspect that's a lot of java scripting when the simpler method was let magic do some alignment analysis IF possible. See this modified demo out put from the mentioned app (where app result should look better) but the app is not free after 14 days trial win/mac/linux https://filetransfer.io/data-package/3yMeagX9#link

@KJ: Personally I don't want the overalying, I want side-by-side. Overlying is another method of comparison between screenshots which is relevant in other contexts than mine.

that's simpler adjust the frames to be left and right that was a pull from that apps output designed for overlay by set the negative shift but positives would be separate images the key is having a third which could be the highlighted differences but without you try image magic or similar no way to see the differences you have in your mind. Personally for spot the difference when same size (like the puzzles) I do 2 pdf and quickly flip the tabs for my lazy eye to spot the shifting changes.

What about https://www.diffchecker.com/image-compare/ ?
You are able to

place images next to each other
place images one-over-the-other (including a slider)

It does not render text though, but you can distiguish them using the image file name, which is shown in the interface.
They don't share a common canvas though...
So, no perfect solution for your requirements, but maybe good enough?
It is free and runs in your browser, so also available on linux.
